# Is Cocos2d-x a good development platform for games?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have just learnt Cocos2d, but i am not an expert on it. But a friend told me to learn Cocos2d-x. Should i prefer Cocos2d-x on Cocos2d? I have heard the technologies which are used Multiplatforms developments are not as good as the native's. Can someone help in this regard? Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocos2d-x:

> Cocos2d-X is a game engine framework based on Cocos2d-iPhone, which
>   consists of expanding supported platforms, with multiple choice of
>   programming languages thats shares the same API structure.
>
> Programmers can choose to use their preferred language to achieve
>   their targeted platform Native branch written in C++, with a little
>   Java and Objective-C. Lua and javascript are binded as scripting
>   language. HTML5 branch, also known as cocos2d-html5, is written in
>   Javascript, that focuses on desktop browsers XNA port, is written in
>   C#, focus on Windows Phone 7 and XNA.

If your aim is iPhone/iPad you should stick with Cocos2d. There is OpenGL ES, but the learning curve would make you take a lot of time to learn the basics and then start doing more complex stuff. Cocos2d is an abstraction build on top of OpenGL ES, which will make you start getting results quite fast. In my opinion, Cocos2d is a good choice. There also lot's of information on the internet comparing both alternatives and others.

Comment: we don't have OpenGL ES in cocos2d-x?

Comment: For what I read, cocos2d-x doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0, which is something you should try to develop with, if you go into the OpenGL path.

Comment: yes, i agree. OpenGL is a must for games.

Comment: Saleh, check this question I made a couple of months ago, it could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669018/advantages-of-using-core-graphics

Comment: Thanks man. Its an informative post.

Answer (score 1):

I think, any cross-platform framework have it's own restrictions. I think, that if you are already familiar with objective-c, you should use cocos2d-iphone. If you are more familiar with c++, you can use cocos2d-x.

As for me, I tried both these frameworks, and can say, that cocos2d-iphone is much more faster for the development because of using many native objective-c things, that cannot be used in c++. I don't say, that C++ is a bad language, just it is too uncomfortable for me.

Both frameworks has the same structure, so you can migrate freely later. Your can improve your knowledge of cocos2d on any of these two frameworks

Comment: yes, i have experience in objective-c and i am quite comfortable with it. And with your explanation cocos2d-iphone is a good choice for me.