# Cocos2d or cocos 2d x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Im starting to learn iPhone dev, I've looked at the basics and am now looking at cocos2d for games etc.

My question is should I start with cocos2d or should I start with cocos2d x?

Im interested in multi platform but is it important to have a good understanding of cocos2d before jumping into X?

Comment: use search before asking question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205877/is-cocos2d-x-a-good-development-platform-for-games

Comment: read this for "choosing the right engine" advice: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/05/the-game-engine-dating-guide-how-to-find-the-right-engine-for-your-game/

Answer (score 0):

Start using cocos2d-x ,its much better than cocos2d-iphone. see cocos2d-x.org you will know more.

Answer (score 0):

If your target platform is explicitly the iPhone cocos2d-iphone would probably be the simplest to set up and since it uses objective-c, it would be the most natural transition if you have already done any development on the iPhone.

If you ever intend to release across mobile platforms, or prefer to develop with c++, then cocos2d-x would be your best bet.

Both projects are on coordinated release schedules, and so should be on par as far as features and support.

Both have decent communities with lots of tutorials, so it's a draw there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, cocos2d-x has javascript-binding (jsb) and lua-binding, which let you write all your game logic in scripts while all graphics stuff runs as native, giving you both quick development and high run-time performance. With jsb, one can also quickly switch to cocos2d-html5 with none-to-little code change.