# cocos2d-iphone or cocos2d-x for game development?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

We are a small team (two people) intending to develop mobile device games. Initially it will be on iOS only, but will be ported to android/windows phone. Cocos2d seems to be the best open source game engine for now. The problem I'm discussing with co-worker is whether we should use cocos2d-iphone (object-c) or cocos2d-x (c++).

We both have quite some experience with C++, and I have played around with object-c for couple months in spare time. It is not that difficult to use object-c, but C++ is still more preferable.

Initially I intend to use cocos2d-iphone since most online documents/examples are based on cocos2d-iphone. After playing around some cocos2d-x samples, I feel they are quite similar. Considering we will port the game to android or windows phone, it's probably better to use the c++ based cocos2d-x for game engine related code, so it will be easier when porting the game.

If anyone has practical working experience with cocos2d-x, could you share your thought or comment? Which one will you choose? cocos2d-iphone or cocos2d-x? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is cocos2d-x a good development platform for games?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205877/is-cocos2d-x-a-good-development-platform-for-games)

Answer (score 2):

cocos2d-x is hard to integrate with Platform specified features, such as UITableView, GameCentre... but good for cross-platform.

If you are using a lot iOS based libs, I think cocos2d-iphone will be the best choice.

If your game are running totally independent from the Platform (for example, never use camera, microphone, network, database), then cocos2d-x will be a great framework.

Actually, database is fine since you can plugin the sqlite in most of the platforms without any problem.