# Graphics for a iOS 2D Game

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, rendering, 2d

I've already published a 2D game on the App Store, but I've noticed that when I add too many objects, the fps drop down, and it's a quite simple game, so I believe it shouldn't happen.

So I think that I'm not rendering the graphics properly.

What should I use, OpenGL ES, Quartz 2D, ...?

I've been reading Apple's documents about OpenGL ES for iOS, but they hardly ever mention 2D, so I'm not sure if it can be used for this.

I'm now using Quartz 2D, (I guess it's UIView, UIImages, UIImageViews), but in fact, I'm not using the drawRect method of the views, ever. I create the images or graphics within the init function of the view, and a save them into a variable if I need to modify their properties later.

Any suggestion, recommendation, pdf would be highly appreciated! :)

PS: Here's a link to the game, if you want to have a better idea about it: http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/kipos/id494638587?mt=8

Comment: You actually check a question I made on SO some time ago. [Here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669018/advantages-of-using-core-graphics

Comment: belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com, especially because this is an opinion-heavy question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use Cocos2D. Its features will make game development a lot easier for you. If you think you're up for a challenge, try OpenGL ES. I'll warn you though: it has a *very* steep learning curve.