# Best 2D/3D Game engine for a map-based game in iOS

Tags: ios, game-engine

I am not very familiar with Game engines for iOS app. Can anyone suggest an open source game engine for my game development?

My game scenario is as follows: The user selects a map, and a character inside of the game I moves through a path predefined in the map.

I was thinking about writing this game in OpenGL but it seems like I have to write a huge amount of code. Do any game engines exist in which I can successfully write this game?

Comment: belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com, especially because this is an opinion-heavy question

Answer (score 2):

Lua is easier to learn than Objective-C. There are several Lua development environments:

Gideros Studio: http://www.giderosmobile.com/

Corona SDK: http://www.coronalabs.com/

Moai: http://getmoai.com/

My favourite is Gideros Studio, because it seemed to me the easiest to get started, and is free until you want to remove the splash screen, and has a very friendly forum with access to the developers. You can also include native plugins (Objective C and C++ for Android).

Moai is the only actual open source one, if you really need to change the source, but it is probably the hardest one to learn.

Comment: if we can't change the splash screen then it will be irritating. Is there any other way to change splash screen without purchasing?

Comment: No, you need to pay $149 to be able to change the splash screen. That is how future Gideros Studio development is funded.

Answer (score 1):

cocos2d is popular and easy to use and learn. you could also use kobald2d as that includes cocos2d and other frameworks as well. you can download them through a search on google

Answer (score 1):

As state by the other user cocos2d would be a good solution for what you want. Although you asked for "open source", you can always check, **for free**, [Unity for iOS](http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/ios). You could also check a question I made some time ago, which can give you some hints of some options you have, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669018/advantages-of-using-core-graphics). From the [Unity site](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses):

> Oh, and don't forget that Unity is free and we have fully-functional
>   30-day trials available for Unity Pro and Unity iOS Pro!

I know it's not perfect, but still, if you see it's worth, it can make a huge difference in your project.

Comment: Don't you need to pay like $1000+ for a licence to get the app from Unity game engine to your iOS device?

Comment: I had Unity for iOS for free. You don't have access to all the goodies, but you can at least see what you are able to do with it. You can check the trial here => http://unity3d.com/unity/download/ You can also check the different licenses here => http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Comment: but free version is enough for my scenario? as I wanted develop a game which have some map and my main character will not go outside of the map.

Comment: I don't really know. As almost everything in the world, you will have to try to see if it fits your particular need..

Answer (score 1):

Try [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/), it's not free, but it is a good engine that doesnt require a lot of code

Comment: Yeah, Stencyl is not bad. And they do have a free version or a trial of some kind. It has a pretty decent tile based system, which makes doing large terrains or maps pretty handy.